# How to merge Trade ticks with Bid_Ask ticks from IB API reqHistoricalTicks, like the Time&Sales window?

Tags: historical-data, tick-data, interactive-brokers

`reqHistoricalTicks` returns data with 1 second precision, so only looking at timestamp is not enough to merge them. But it seems that the Time&Sales window in TWS is able to consistently present historical tick data in exactly the merged format I want (except it also only has 1 second precision), including rows where the Bid/Ask changed with no trades taking place:

[image]

How can I get this format from the API? Is TWS using some tricks/assumptions to merge the two data sources, or is there another undocumented endpoint that provides pre-merged data?